# Zurb Foundation - Create a custom form but now posts wont be created

Tags: html, css, django, forms, zurb-foundation

so I created a form for the website Im building using Foundation Forms, and now it wont create the post.

Here is the html:

```
<div style="padding-bottom: 5px; padding-top: 10px;">
<label>
    <h3><small><font color="black">Post Title</font></small></h3>
    <input type="text" placeholder="Enter Post Title Here">
</label>
</div>
<!--Post Content-->
<div style="padding-bottom: 5px;">
<label>
  <h3><small><font color="black">Post Content</font></small></h3>
  <textarea placeholder="Enter Post Content Here"></textarea>
</label>
<hr>
</div>
<!--Post File-->
<label for="exampleFileUpload" class="button">Upload File</label>
<input type="file" id="exampleFileUpload" class="show-for-sr">
<br>
<hr>
<!--Submit Post-->
<label>
<input name= "myfiles" type='submit' class='button' value='Create Post'/>
</label>
</form>
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You mean the HTTP post is not "posting"?  It looks like you are missing the starting `<form>` tag and it's not a Zurb issue.